# Collection should return null or empty upon a Db load ending with no records found?

Tags: collections

If you have a method that queries the DB and returns a collection populated with the records found, what should be returned upon no records found?

- A new collection with `.Count` == 0
- null

Is there any consensus on this?

Or returning null and returning an empty collection should have different meanings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return an empty collection. That will avoid you to check every time that you got a null as return.

You will always have a code like (abstract code):

```
for index = 0 to collection.size
  // do operations
```

instead of:

```
if collection != null 
  for index = 0 to collection.size
    // do operations
```

Additionally, you could extend this to the [NULL Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) if you need more complex behavior from your collection.